# Identify unlocalized text

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, asp.net-4.0

In ASP.NET, an application can be localized using resource files. Resource files hold different translations. For example, one might have an English resource file and a Spanish resource file. When resource files are used, an attribute can be applied to controls on a web page to automatically populate that control with values from a resource file. Alternatively, the values can be programmatically loaded from a resource file and assigned to a control's property.

ASP.NET uses a fallback mechanism for loading translations. It tries to find the resource file that is most similar to the current user's culture. If the current user's culture is Spanish, ASP.NET tries to load the appropriate resource from the Spanish resource file. If the Spanish resource is not available, it falls back to a default resource file. Because of this behavior, text for a Spanish user may be shown in the default language for two reasons:

1. No Spanish translation is available. (The translators haven't provided a translation for this item yet.)
2. The text is not localized. (This may be the result of plain text appearing in the page or the message being hard-coded somewhere.)

If text appears in the default language, I want to know whether it was because of reason 1 or because of reason 2.

For every missing translation, I could insert some kind of placeholder text in a resource file. However, this means that I am throwing away the fallback mechanism. Even worse, if placeholder text accidentally makes it through to production, it looks much worse than showing the default text.

Does anyone have any suggestions (or solutions) for determining which of these two conditions is the reason for default text appearing during manual testing?

Comment: I have toyed with the idea of somehow overriding the fallback behavior of the resource fetcher. Based on some config setting, if a resource for a language is missing we would either fallback to English or show English_code. There is an excellent article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx. Unfortunately, it sounds like I may need to write quite a bit of code to get this fairly simple sounding change made. This makes me think: is there a different solution entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to verify that every localizable text is indeed in fact localizable and not burned in the code. To do this you should not be using a real culture (Spanish), instead you should create resources for a fake unsupported culture and provide an automatic translation for every localizable resource entry available in the default resources.

For example, if you have a default resource containing:

- Entry1: This is a test!

you should create a resource in your fake culture containing:

- Entry1: Th1s 1s @ t€st!

You could even (and should) perform the creation of the fake resources automatically using a simple character mapping. This way, when you set the application to use your custom fake culture you know that every entry has a translation so you can find harcoded text. **This strategy is used by Windows** and is known as [pseudo-locales](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The use of pseudo translated strings makes it possible do development using the fake culture because the text is still readable and this **improves your probability of finding hardcoded text**.

Windows supports pseudo-locales since Windows Vista and Windows 2008 R2, so if your build and testing environment uses these operating systems you can associate your fake culture to one of these pseudo locales (for example `qps-ploc`). If you have unsupported operating systems just associate your fake resources to a real culture that you probably will never be supporting or just create your own culture.

Also note that even in a supported operating system, Visual Studio will not create satellite assemblies for these pseudo-locales unless you [enable them on the registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).